# REST solutions when not strictly referring to an actual resource

Tags: api, rest

Take a simple table `person`:

```
CREATE TABLE person
(
  id bigint,
  name nvarchar(128),
  age int
)
```

You can represent this in a REST interface:

```
GET /person
GET /person/5
PUT /person
POST /person/5
PATCH /person/5
DELETE /person/5
```

This interface would expect 2 parameters:

```
{ 
  name: 'Joe',
  age: 16,
}
```

You could then define an API that would expect those two parameters, and even make the `age` optional.

However, suppose you wanted to define a model on the client side that wanted to do fancy things with this `person` table, such as pulling all teenagers, how would you best represent this?

I suppose I could do something this, only support `GET`, and then arbitrarily require different parameters which matched the query needs:

```
GET /person/teenager
```

However, I don't know that this would properly meet all use cases. For example, I believe REST urls should only have nouns, and I am not sure how to put something like this into noun form:

```
GET /person/by-age
```

Any ideas / references / suggestions?

Comment: I'd use a GET parameter to add arguments to the resource to filter it out. I often saw usage like: /person/filter?min-age=13&max-age=20 . Not sure whether this is good REST though.

Comment: That could be a good idea. Filter would be a noun and could be a generic add-on to a lot of objects.

Answer (score 2):

The most common way to constrain your person listing results is to use query parameters.  You can define your query parameters in any way that is useful for your API.  One example might be `GET /person?age=13..20` to get only teenagers.  Another example might be `GET /person/?filter=age>=13,age<20`.